# app crashes on iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode6.4

I am new to iOS. I have created a ipa file using Xcode 6.4, which is working fine on 8.X. but recently we tried it on iPhone 6 with iOS 9, and the app get crashed after splash screen. does anyone faced this problem?

**crash log**

```
Incident Identifier: E4ACE339-8187-48DF-BACC-75B0E5476D58
CrashReporter Key:   ac2769bff5db3be2b771695a24c3809680e077a9
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             <app name> [1851]
Path:                <app path>
Identifier:          <identifier>
Version:             2 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-07 13:07:06.06 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-10-07 13:07:05.05 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @executable_path/TestLib.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A5FDC-2C2E-4A64-B20D-4AF90BD3D8C0/<appName>.app/<appName>
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A5FDC-2C2E-4A64-B20D-4AF90BD3D8C0/<appName>.app/TestLib.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x0060F000, size=0x00003000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A5FDC-2C2E-4A64-B20D-4AF90BD3D8C0/<appName>.app/TestLib.dylib
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A5FDC-2C2E-4A64-B20D-4AF90BD3D8C0/<appName>.app/TestLib.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x00637000, size=0x00003000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A5FDC-2C2E-4A64-B20D-4AF90BD3D8C0/<appName>.app/TestLib.dylib
  Dyld Version: 369.12

Binary Images:
0x8c000 - 0x42ffff <appName> armv7  <d171742a44fc36628a38796e5c37c9dc> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A5FDC-2C2E-4A64-B20D-4AF90BD3D8C0/<appName>.app/<appName>
0x1fee4000 - 0x1ff0bfff dyld armv7s  <208fd9e5719439acb248b91286f1dd33> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: Have you checked the same with the simulator?

Comment: Where is the crash report? You problem is not clear.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the crash? Or can we see your code? Do you know where is the crash? Is so hard to understand where is your problem

Comment: @iApple it is working fine on simulator (ios 8.4)

Comment: @Lorenzo please suggest how to get a crash report from a user.

Comment: edited the crash log.

Comment: @HerrErnstvonFlübbergrübber : the build was exported using Xcode 6.4. for the user with iOS 8.X. one more user added to list with ios 9. who is facing this issue.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting all these down-votes. I am running into the same issue and your crash report looks similar to what i am getting. I have an app that worked just fine in Xcode6, but when i rebuild it with Xcode7, and install on a device, it terminates right during startup with a similar Dyld error message. In my case, the framework that it's having trouble with is AirshipKit (Urban Airship). I have turned Bitcode off but that didn't help. You could try changing your @rpath, your's seems to be missing the /Frameworks directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. the above crash nothing to do with iOS 9 or Xcode 7. we were pushing the app through the MDM(Mobile device Management). MDM was doing a wrapping which was caused to this issue. this was identified by MDM support team. and its working now.

Sorry that I hadn't mentioned about MDM in my post(because I didn't thought that MDM can cause such problem)

Thanks for your comments.